# Application Title Cut Off In VB6

Tags: vb6

Platform: Windows XP
Development Platform: VB6

When trying to set an application title via the Project Properties dialog on the Make tab, it seems to silently cut off the title at a set number of characters.  Also tried this via the App.Title property and it seems to suffer from the same problem.  I wouldn't care about this but the QA Dept. insists that we need to get the entire title displayed.

Does anyone have a workaround or fix for this?

---

Edit: To those who responded about a 40 character limit, that's what I sort of suspected--hence my question about a possible workaround :-) .

Actually I posted this question to try to help a fellow developer so when I see her on Monday, I'll point her to all of your excellent suggestions and see if any of them help her get this straightened out.  I do know that for some reason some of the dialogs displayed by the app seem to pick up the string from the App.Title setting which is why she had asked me about the limitation on the length of the string.

I just wish I could find something definitive from Microsoft (like some sort of KB note) so she could show it to our QA department so they'd realize this is simply a limitation of VB.

Comment: Did you try setting the title on the main form? And when you say "application title" do you mean the title displayed on the taskbar, or the one displayed on the main form of the application?

Comment: Yes. The Message Box that inherits the application title gets messed up.

Comment: By default the MsgBox function will use App.Title in the titlebar of the message box window, or the project name (if you leave App.Title blank). You can override this by explicitly passing a string for the Title parameter, or use dummy's suggestion and override the default MsgBox function.

Comment: From what I can remember App.Title is used as the default title for MsgBox, the application name for DDE, and as the caption in Task Manager. From the mention of dialogs in the question, I think its the MsgBox calls that are causing concern so I think dummy's suggestion is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### One solution using the Windows API

**Disclaimer**: *IMHO this seems like overkill just to meet the requirement stated in the question, but in the spirit of giving a (hopefully) complete answer to the problem, here goes nothing...*

Here is a working version I came up with after looking around in MSDN for awhile, until I finally came upon an article on vbAccelerator that got my wheels turning.

- See the [vbAccelerator](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Get_System_Display_Fonts_and_Non-Client_Area_Sizes/article.asp) page for the original article (not directly related to the question, but there was enough there for me to formulate an answer)

The basic premise is to first calculate the width of the form's caption text and then to use **GetSystemMetrics** to get the width of various bits of the window, such as the border and window frame width, the width of the Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons, and so on (I split these into their own functions for readibility/clarity). We need to account for these parts of the window in order to calculate an accurate new width for the form.

In order to accurately calculate the width ("extent") of the form's caption, we need to get the system caption font, hence the **SystemParametersInfo** and **CreateFontIndirect** calls and related goodness.

The end result all this effort is the **GetRecommendedWidth** function, which calculates all of these values and adds them together, plus a bit of extra padding so that there is some space between the last character of the caption and the control buttons. If this new width is greater than the form's current width, GetRecommendedWidth will return this (larger) width, otherwise, it will return the Form's current width.

I only tested it briefly, but it appears to work fine. Since it uses Windows API functions, however, you may want to exercise caution, especially since it's copying memory around. I didn't add robust error-handling, either.

By the way, if someone has a cleaner, less-involved way of doing this, or if I missed something in my own code, please let me know.

**To try it out, paste the following code into a new module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type SIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type

Private Const LF_FACESIZE = 32

'NMLOGFONT: This declaration came from vbAccelerator (here is what he says about it):'
'                                                                  '
' For some bizarre reason, maybe to do with byte                   '
' alignment, the LOGFONT structure we must apply                   '
' to NONCLIENTMETRICS seems to require an LF_FACESIZE              '
' 4 bytes smaller than normal:                                     '

Private Type NMLOGFONT
   lfHeight As Long
   lfWidth As Long
   lfEscapement As Long
   lfOrientation As Long
   lfWeight As Long
   lfItalic As Byte
   lfUnderline As Byte
   lfStrikeOut As Byte
   lfCharSet As Byte
   lfOutPrecision As Byte
   lfClipPrecision As Byte
   lfQuality As Byte
   lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
   lfFaceName(LF_FACESIZE - 4) As Byte
End Type

Private Type LOGFONT
   lfHeight As Long
   lfWidth As Long
   lfEscapement As Long
   lfOrientation As Long
   lfWeight As Long
   lfItalic As Byte
   lfUnderline As Byte
   lfStrikeOut As Byte
   lfCharSet As Byte
   lfOutPrecision As Byte
   lfClipPrecision As Byte
   lfQuality As Byte
   lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
   lfFaceName(LF_FACESIZE) As Byte
End Type

Private Type NONCLIENTMETRICS
   cbSize As Long
   iBorderWidth As Long
   iScrollWidth As Long
   iScrollHeight As Long
   iCaptionWidth As Long
   iCaptionHeight As Long
   lfCaptionFont As NMLOGFONT
   iSMCaptionWidth As Long
   iSMCaptionHeight As Long
   lfSMCaptionFont As NMLOGFONT
   iMenuWidth As Long
   iMenuHeight As Long
   lfMenuFont As NMLOGFONT
   lfStatusFont As NMLOGFONT
   lfMessageFont As NMLOGFONT
End Type

Private Enum SystemMetrics
    SM_CXBORDER = 5
    SM_CXDLGFRAME = 7
    SM_CXFRAME = 32
    SM_CXSCREEN = 0
    SM_CXICON = 11
    SM_CXICONSPACING = 38
    SM_CXSIZE = 30
    SM_CXEDGE = 45
    SM_CXSMICON = 49
    SM_CXSMSIZE = 52
End Enum

Private Const SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS = 41
Private Const SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS = 42

Private Declare Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" _
    (ByVal hdc As Long, _
     ByVal lpszString As String, _
     ByVal cbString As Long, _
     lpSize As SIZE) As Long

Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As SystemMetrics) As Long

Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" ( _
   ByVal uAction As Long, _
   ByVal uParam As Long, _
   lpvParam As Any, _
   ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateFontIndirect Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateFontIndirectA" (lpLogFont As LOGFONT) As Long

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Function GetCaptionTextWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    '-----------------------------------------------'
    ' This function does the following:             '
    '                                               '
    '   1. Get the font used for the forms caption  '
    '   2. Call GetTextExtent32 to get the width in '
    '      pixels of the forms caption              '
    '   3. Convert the width from pixels into       '
    '      the scaling mode being used by the form  '
    '                                               '
    '-----------------------------------------------'

    Dim sz As SIZE
    Dim hOldFont As Long
    Dim hCaptionFont As Long
    Dim CaptionFont As LOGFONT
    Dim ncm As NONCLIENTMETRICS

    ncm.cbSize = LenB(ncm)

    If SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, ncm, 0) = 0 Then
        ' What should we do if we the call fails? Change as needed for your app,'
        ' but this call is unlikely to fail anyway'
        Exit Function
    End If

    CopyMemory CaptionFont, ncm.lfCaptionFont, LenB(CaptionFont)

    hCaptionFont = CreateFontIndirect(CaptionFont)
    hOldFont = SelectObject(frm.hdc, hCaptionFont)

    GetTextExtentPoint32 frm.hdc, frm.Caption, Len(frm.Caption), sz
    GetCaptionTextWidth = frm.ScaleX(sz.cx, vbPixels, frm.ScaleMode)

    'clean up, otherwise bad things will happen...'
    DeleteObject (SelectObject(frm.hdc, hOldFont))

End Function

Private Function GetControlBoxWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    Dim nButtonWidth As Long
    Dim nButtonCount As Long
    Dim nFinalWidth As Long

    If frm.ControlBox Then

        nButtonCount = 1                            'close button is always present'
        nButtonWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE)  'get width of a single button in the titlebar'

        ' account for min and max buttons if they are visible'
        If frm.MinButton Then nButtonCount = nButtonCount + 1
        If frm.MaxButton Then nButtonCount = nButtonCount + 1

        nFinalWidth = nButtonWidth * nButtonCount

    End If

    'convert to whatever scale the form is using'
    GetControlBoxWidth = frm.ScaleX(nFinalWidth, vbPixels, frm.ScaleMode)

End Function

Private Function GetIconWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    Dim nFinalWidth As Long

    If frm.ControlBox Then

        Select Case frm.BorderStyle

            Case vbFixedSingle, vbFixedDialog, vbSizable:
                'we have an icon, gets its width'
                nFinalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON)
            Case Else:
                'no icon present, so report zero width'
                nFinalWidth = 0

        End Select

    End If

    'convert to whatever scale the form is using'
    GetIconWidth = frm.ScaleX(nFinalWidth, vbPixels, frm.ScaleMode)

End Function

Private Function GetFrameWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    Dim nFinalWidth As Long

    If frm.ControlBox Then

        Select Case frm.BorderStyle

            Case vbFixedSingle, vbFixedDialog:
                nFinalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME)
            Case vbSizable:
                nFinalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME)
        End Select

    End If

    'convert to whatever scale the form is using'
    GetFrameWidth = frm.ScaleX(nFinalWidth, vbPixels, frm.ScaleMode)

End Function

Private Function GetBorderWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    Dim nFinalWidth As Long

    If frm.ControlBox Then

        Select Case frm.Appearance

            Case 0 'flat'
                nFinalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER)
            Case 1 '3D'
                nFinalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE)
        End Select

    End If

    'convert to whatever scale the form is using'
    GetBorderWidth = frm.ScaleX(nFinalWidth, vbPixels, frm.ScaleMode)

End Function

Public Function GetRecommendedWidth(ByVal frm As Form) As Long

    Dim nNewWidth As Long

    ' An abitrary amount of extra padding so that the caption text '
    ' is not scrunched up against the min/max/close buttons '

    Const PADDING_TWIPS = 120

    nNewWidth = _
        GetCaptionTextWidth(frm) _
        + GetControlBoxWidth(frm) _
        + GetIconWidth(frm) _
        + GetFrameWidth(frm) * 2 _
        + GetBorderWidth(frm) * 2 _
        + PADDING_TWIPS

    If nNewWidth > frm.Width Then
        GetRecommendedWidth = nNewWidth
    Else
        GetRecommendedWidth = frm.Width
    End If

End Function
```

**Then place the following in your Form_Load event**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.Caption = String(100, "x") 'replace this with your caption'
    Me.Width = GetRecommendedWidth(Me)

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so I'm accepting it but as the person who gave the answer stated it is sort of overkill for the issue.

Comment: The reason for the comment on the VBAccelerator code "For some bizarre reason..." is that the original API declaration from 1994 (wow!) was incorrect, and was corrected in 1999. If you change the LOGFONT line `lfFaceName(LF_FACESIZE - 4) As Byte` to `lfFaceName(1 to LF_FACESIZE) As Byte` then it will still work and you don't need a separate NMLOGFONT type and you won't be snipping off part of the font name if it happens to be 32 characters. HTH

Answer (score 4):

The MsgBox-Function takes a parameter for the title. If you dont want to change every single call to the MsgBox-Function, you could "override" the default behavior:

```
Function MsgBox(Prompt, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional Title, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context) As VbMsgBoxResult
    If IsMissing(Title) Then Title = String(40, "x") & "abc"
    MsgBox = Interaction.MsgBox(Prompt, Buttons, Title, HelpFile, Context)
End Function
```

Edit: As Mike Spross notes: This only hides the normal MsgBox-Function. If you wanted to access your custom MsgBox from another project, you would have to qualify it.

Comment: You may want to point out that this "override" only works as intended for code in the same project, because within the same project, your MsgBox function "hides" the version in the Interaction library. If you wanted to access your custom MsgBox from another project, you would have to qualify it.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a Standard EXE project in the IDE and typed text into the application title field under the Project Properties Make tab until I filled the field. From this quick test, it appears that App.Title is limited to 40 characters. Next I tried it in code by putting the following code in the default form (Form1) created for the project:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    App.Title = String(41, "X")
    MsgBox Len(App.Title)
End Sub
```

This quick test confirms the 40-characater limit, because the MsgBox displays 40, even though the code attempts to set App.Title to a 41-character string.

If it's really important to get the full string to display in the titlebar of a Form, then only way I can think of to ensure that the entire title is displayed would be to get the width of the titlebar text and use that to increase the width of your Form so that it can accommodate the complete title string. I may come back and post code for this if I can find the right API incantations, but it might look something like this in the Form_Load event:

```
Dim nTitleBarTextWidth As Long
Dim nNewWidth As Long

Me.Caption = "My really really really really really long app title here"

' Get titlebar text width (somehow) '
nTitleBarTextWidth = GetTitleBarTextWidth()

' Compute the new width for the Form such that the title will fit within it '
' (May have to add a constant to this to make sure the title fits correctly) '
nNewWidth = Me.ScaleX(nTitleBarTextWidth, vbPixels, Me.ScaleMode)

' If the new width is bigger than the forms current size, use the new width '
If nNewWidth > Me.Width Then
    Form.Width = nNewWidth
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that VB6 limits the App.Title property to 40 characters. Unfortunately, I can't locate any documentation on MSDN detailing this behavior. (And unfortunately, I don't have documentation loaded onto the machine where my copy of VB6 still resides.)

I ran an experiment with long titles, and that was the observed behavior. If your title is longer than 40 characters, it simply will get truncated.